# terraform-compliance ERROR: is not a valid terraform plan json output

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

Description:
I'm working with terraform-compliance and it doesn't seem to want to accept standard json files that the docs say to use. I created an issue on the github, but thought I would extend it here in case I'm missing something which is entirely possible.

OS: macos catalina

running docker

terraform-compliance v1.2.7

I'm just running the scripts on the docs, and it doesn't seem to work when I pass it proper json files. Is this still maintained?

To Reproduce

```
# main.tf
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

locals {
  common_tags = {
    Environment        = var.env_name
    TerraformWorkspace = var.env_name
  }
}

terraform {
  backend "remote" {
    organization = "*******"
    workspaces {
      prefix = "******"
    }
  }
}
```

```
# variables.tf
variable "region" {
  description = "AWS region"
}

variable "env_name" {
}
```

*Used terraform-compliance parameters* I'm not sure what is meant by this?

Should I be running these in docker??

```sh
$ terraform show -json > state.out.json
$ terraform state pull > state.out
$ terraform-compliance -p state.out.json
# terraform-compliance v1.2.7 initiated

# ERROR: state.out.json is not a valid terraform plan json output.
```

Tested versions :

- terraform-compliance v1.2.7
- Terraform v0.12.26
- Python 2.7.16

Comment: It's not asking for the state file. It wants the plan output. `terraform-compliance` is meant to be ran incrementally and should be used to block denied changes before they happen rather than tell you what should have been blocked that already exists.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Thanks kind stranger! I noticed in the docs that you can pass it a state file or a plan file depending on your features. So if I try to use the plan.out or plan.out.json they both fail with a similar message. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Could it be because of the how you pull/convert the state file ?

Normally you should first pull, then convert the pulled state file, e.g. ;

`terraform state pull > state.out && terraform show -json state.out > state.out.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`states` are also supported, as well as `plan` outputs. There must be something within your state file that `terraform-compliance` is not happy about.

Just tried the same and it works. Is it possible to share the state file privately (assuming there will be sensitive information inside) with the maintainer ? or maybe strip some parts - but I guess that will be harder to do.